# Python 3.3: Birthday Probability

Tags: python

Trying to do the Birthday Program in python. Being a beginner in Python, I am having some trouble.

1. Function *duplicates(l)* that takes a list l and returns True if it has a duplicate element, and False if it does not.
2. Function *test(count)* generates a list of *count* random integers between 1 and 365 . Function duplicates(l) will test for duplicates.
3. Function *probability(count, num)* runs *num* tests of *count* people, and counts the number of tests with duplicates. It returns the fraction of the tests with duplicates - the number of duplicates divided by num.

results should look like:

For  2 people, the probability of 2 birthdays is 0.002.

For  3 people, the probability of 2 birthdays is 0.008. and so on...

---

Stuck on step 2 & 3:

```
import random

# not sure what to put for count
count = [random.randint(1, 365)]

def duplicates(l):
    if len(l)!=len(set(l)):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def test(count):
    return [random.randint(1, 365)]

#def probability(count,num):
```

I believe I did step one correctly, but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: A little help with step 2: `def test(count): return [random.randint(1,365) for x in range(count)]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create the list like this. `test` isn't a very useful name. Consider something like `make_birthday_list` instead

```
def test(count):
    return [random.randint(1, 365) for x in range(count)]
```

The test in duplicates already evaluates to a bool, so you can just do this. It's not a good idea to use `l` as a variable name (looks too much like `1`) so I changed it to `the_list`

```
def duplicates(the_list):
    return len(the_list)!=len(set(the_list))
```

You'll have to run the test [over and over](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method) to get the probability

eg.

```
num_samples = 10000
for count in range(100):
    dup = 0
    for test_number in range(num_samples):
        the_list = make_birthday_list(count)
        if duplicates(the_list):
            dup += 1
    print(count, dup/num_samples)   # / returns a float in Python3
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I learned a lot about Python from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

`test` does not return a list of length `count`. The result only has one element. You would want to make use of list comprehension to get this to work nice:

```
[random.randint(1, 365) for x in range(count)]
```

Then for step 3:

```
def probability(count,num):
    dup_trues = sum([duplicates(test(count)) for i in range(num)])  #***
    dup_falses = num-dup_trues
    return float(fails)/num
```

The host important line in the above function is labeled `#***`
Here's a breakdown of how it works:

The stuff in the square brackets is a list comprehension.

`for i in range(num)` says do this stuff with i=0, i=1, ...i=num-1. You know what duplicates and test does. So the list ends up with a bunch of trues and falses (ones and zeros)

`sum` adds up the elements of the list. So this gives us the number of trues

The next line `dup_falses = num-dup_trues` says we have num results altogether, those that aren't true are false.

`return float(fails)/num` the `float` is not necessary in python 3